# Launch instance script from Python and AWS cookbook does not create any instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am currently working my way through the Python and AWS cookbook from O'Reilly publishing. I'm currently having a look at the launch instance script which I had working (Which - funny story - I didnt think was working, till I clicked on another region in AWS and saw I had created around 50 instances trying to get script working... Lesson for people new to AWS: Always set and know your default region).

Now for some reason the script seems to run without any errors, but in the interactive python shell nothing seems to print out and no instances are created. I dont know what I have changed to stop this working. In some testing I have done (basically importing boto in interactive mode and connecting to EC2 from there), it seems to successfully connect so I have no idea what is causing this.

The script is below, so if anyone can help or tell me any tests that I can do, that would be great:

```
import os
import time
import boto
import boto.manage.cmdshell

def launch_instance(ami="i-7ef58184",
                    instance_type="t1.micro",
                    key_name="paws",
                    key_extension=".pem",
                    key_dir="~/.ssh",
                   group_name="paws",
                    ssh_port="22",
                    cidr="0.0.0.0/0",
                    tag="paws",
                    user_data=None,
                    cmd_shell=True,
                    login_user="ec2-user",
                    ssh_passwd=None):
    cmd = None

    ec2 = boto.connect_ec2() # Crededentials are stored in /etc/boto.cfg
    ec2 = boto.connect_ec2(debug=2)
    try:
        key = ec2.get_all_key_pairs(keynames=[key_name])[0]
    except ec2.ResponseError, e:
        if e.code == 'InvalidKeyPair.NotFound':
                print 'Creating keypair %s' % key_name
                key = ec2.create_key_pair(key_name)
                key.save(key_dir)


        else:
            raise
        try:
            group = ec2.get_all_security_groups(groupnames=[group_name])[0]
        except ec2.ResponseError, e:
            if e.code == 'InvalidGroup.NotFound':
                print'Creating security group %s' % group_name
                group = ec2.create_security_group(group_name,
                                                  'A group that allows SSH access')
            else:
                raise
        try:
            group.authorize('tcp',ssh_port,ssh_port,cidr)
        except ec2.ResponseError, e:
            if e.code == 'InvalidPermission.Duplicate':
                print ('Security group %s already authorized') % group_name
            else:
                raise
            reservation = ec2.run_instances(ami,
                                        key_name=key_name,
                                        security_groups=[group_name],
                                        instance_type=instance_type,
                                        user_data=user_data)
            instance = reservation.instances[0]
            print 'waiting for instance...'
            while instance.state != 'running':
                time.sleep(30)
                instance.update()
                print 'Instance is now running'
                print 'Instance IP is %s' % instance.ip_address
                instance.add_tag(tag)


            if cmd_shell:
                key_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(key_dir),
                                        key_name+key_extension)
                cmd = boto.manage.sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                                          key_path,
                                                          username=login_user)
                return (instance, cmd)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: And did you remember to call the `launch_instance`

Comment: @Darren Dow Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question,  hoping it can be understood a little better that way. I hope you still like it :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala how do you mean with did I remember to call the launch_instance I am a complete novice in terms of Python so it is very likely?

Comment: If this is all the code, it defines a function called `launch_instance`; you need to call that function or nothing happens.

Comment: I cannot figure this out so I go to the python command prompt and insert from ec2_launch _instance import launch_instance() and then launch_instance() but still nothing shows and the instance does run any ideas? @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you have indented all code to be run within the `except` of keypair creation. Since you already have created the keys and they are available, the exception is not thrown and the entire `except` block is skipped. You need to **unindent/dedent** your following code by 4 spaces.

```
try:
    key = ec2.get_all_key_pairs(keynames=[key_name])[0]
except ec2.ResponseError, e:
    if e.code == 'InvalidKeyPair.NotFound':
            print 'Creating keypair %s' % key_name
            key = ec2.create_key_pair(key_name)
            key.save(key_dir)


    else:
        raise

### this should be at this level
try:
    ...
```

The same applies to the security group handling - you want to continue whether or not an exception was raised, thus dedent the code as follows:

```
try:
    group.authorize('tcp',ssh_port,ssh_port,cidr)
except ec2.ResponseError, e:
    if e.code == 'InvalidPermission.Duplicate':
        print ('Security group %s already authorized') % group_name
    else:
        raise

### from here on at this level
reservation = ec2.run_instances(ami, ....
```